# How to terminate previous debug session when new one is launched?

Tags: eclipse, myeclipse

In Flash Builder 4 you are able to have the previous debugging session be terminated as soon as you launch a new one. In eclipse previous debugging sessions stick around until you manually terminate them.

Does anyone know if it is possible to have eclipse terminate previous debug sessions when launching a new one, and if so how?

(I am using MyEclipse for Spring 8.6)

Answer (score 2):

Not the best answer but... you could just make terminating easier on yourself, try `Ctrl+F2`

You can also go to `Window > Preferences > General > Keys` and search for *Terminate and Relaunch*. I'm trialing `Alt+F11`.

Alternatively you terminate on build with scripts like here: http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php?t=rview&goto=647327&th=202549

Comment: *Terminate and Relaunch* makes sense. However, you have to normally launch and start debugging the first time (for me this is binded to `F11`), and just then you can use *Terminate and Relaunch* (I binded it to `Shift+F11`).

Answer (score 0):

First launch normal debugging session.
After that, while in debugging mode, you can use *Terminate and Relaunch*.

Here is how to bind the keys to the commands properly (*Window/Preferences -> Settings/General/Keys*):

[image]

In this case it is:

- <kbd>F11</kbd> for *Debug*
- <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F11</kbd> for *Terminate and Relaunch*

Note: when assigning the keys, pay attention to *When* column.

Answer (score -1):

If you press <kbd>Shif</kbd> during launching the new run, the old one will be terminated automatically.